# whether keep two decimal places can solve precision loss

Tags: javascript

The classic precision loss case

```
0.3 - 0.1  // 0.19999999999999998
```

Howerver, if we only calculate number of two decimal places and use **toFixed(2)**, did it is hava a risk?

```
(0.3 - 0.1).toFixed(2)  // '0.20'
```

Comment: It completely depends on your use case, you know what the precision loss is and if your calculations do not loose meaning when you use upto 2 decimal places then why not go ahead use it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can end up getting weird rounding behavior. Maybe don't use it for money

```js
console.log((0.3 - 0.005).toFixed(2))//should be .29
console.log(Math.round((0.3 - 0.005)*100)/100)//should be .3(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js) to solve, it is only 24.4kb

Comment: Oh, this demo is just mine confusion. It's not necessary to import other library

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).